# Como montar um data.frame com elementos iguais de outros dois data.frames

Tags: r, data.frame

Olá,

Eu tenho dois data.frames, cada um com 1 coluna. Um data.frame tem 3701 linhas, enquanto o outro tem mais de 50 mil linhas. O que eu quero é o seguinte: montar um data.frame que contenha apenas os elementos do data.frame com 3701 linhas que estejam presentes no de 50 mil linhas. Eu ja tentei muita coisa, mas não consegui sair do canto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei bem se é isso que você quer, mas pensei no seguinte cenário:

```
df1<-data.frame(a=1:20) # Data frame com apenas 20 elementos
df2<-data.frame(b=11:50) # Data frame com 40 elementos
df3<-df2[which(is.element(df2$b,df1$a)),] # Seleciona os elementos do 
                                          # df2 que estão contidos no df1
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!